# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "finally" y "no finally" (try-catch)?

Tags: java, try-catch

**Diferencia entre terminar con finally:**

```
try {
     // algo
} catch(Exception e) {
     // algo
} finally {
     // algo
}
```

**Y no terminar con finally:**

```
try {
     // algo
} catch(Exception e) {
     // algo
}
// algo (no finally)
```

Yo había leído que en `finally` siempre se ejecuta por más que sea una 'exception' o simplemente cuando no halla errores, pero, ¿no sería lo mismo sin el "`finally`"?, ¿Qué cambia?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal y como dice la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.

lo que viene a decir:

> El bloque `finally` siempre se va a ejecutar cuando el bloque `try` termine. Esto asegura que el bloque `finally` se ejecuta incluso si una excepción inesperada ocurre.

Por lo tanto, aquí podemos ver la principal diferencia. Si no utilizamos el bloque `finally`, si una excepción inesperada ocurre, se ejecutará la parte que esté dentro del bloque `catch` pero solamente eso. De esta manera, te aseguras que también habrá otro código que se ejecutará siempre aunque una excepción ocurra. Además, si ocurre una excepción inesperada al ejecutar el bloque `catch`, el código del bloque `finally` se ejecutará.

**Excepción**

Sin embargo, tal y como indica la documentación, hay en algunos casos en los que el bloque finally podría no ejecutarse:

> **Note**: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

lo que traducido sería:

> **Nota**: Si la Máquina Virtual de Java (JVM) se termina mientras el código del `try` o del `catch` está siendo ejecutado, entonces el bloque `finally` podría no ejecutarse. De la misma manera, si el hilo ejecutando el código del `try` o `catch` es interrumpido o detenido, el bloque `finally` podría no ejecutarse incluso aunque la aplicación en su conjunto continúe.